# C++ Program freezing and UI turn all white

Tags: c++, windows, c++builder

I'm working in a software built in C++ using C++ Builder which is freezing once a month. 
I'm looking in the code but it is too big to find it.
The freezes make the UI gets all white. I tried to simulate this error with some proposital bad codes (null pointers, while(1) and this kind of stuff) but never got the same blank UI.
I ran a What's Hang when it's stopped but I got nothing with it.
Someone knows what can I do in the next time to get more informations which could help me find the reason of the freezing?

Comment: What operating system ? Try stress testing it and/or running under valgrind.

Comment: Ops, is running in Windows XP and using Postgres 8.2

Comment: Run a static analyzer on your code.  Review the code and verify that all return values are checked and all exceptions caught.  Maybe upgrade your compiler.

Comment: Create a *log file* and write significant events that occur, their date and time of occurrence, and any significant data items.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I have a lot of logs in the code in differents stages of the software, but in almost 10 freezes I have no pattern yet. I'm using windowns api which send and receive message with another software, can this cause this kind of error?

Comment: what happens when you attach with the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

A blank (white) UI generally occurs when a UI paint message is queued but not processed.  Simply blocking the message queue from processing new messages is not enough if you don't do something within the UI to trigger a repaint in the first place.

As for troubleshooting the original problem - you should be looking for any code in the main thread that runs longs loop without processing new messages, or long waits on waitable objects using `WaitForSingleObject()` or `WaitForMultipleOBjects()` instead of `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()`, calls to `TThread::WaitFor()` for threads that do not terminate in a timely manner, etc.

It is hard to troubleshoot this kind of problem without knowing what steps the user performs to lead up to the frozen UI so you know what code to start looking at.